# Using an iTerm color scheme inside a Vim :terminal window

Tags: terminal, colorscheme, iterm2, color

My normal terminal color scheme is set via a color preset in iTerm. When I open a terminal window in Vim (`:terminal`) that color scheme doesn't get applied, presumably because Vim has no knowledge of it and instead falls back to the settings in my `.bashrc` file. Is there a way I can fix this and make the Vim terminal window use the same scheme as my normal terminal?

Comment: Idk anything about how iTerm colorschemes work, but in Terminal.app the colorscheme is applied to application windows. Vim just displays text in a :terminal—the application or program might color it with escapes and predetermined backgrounds.